# Domain Aggregate Root with tree of Entities

Tags: design-patterns, tree, domain-driven-design, entity, cqrs

One property of my aggregate root **Node** is a tree like group of entities **Task**. Like

```
- Node
    - Name
    - Release
    - User
    - task
       - task
       - task
            - task
       - task
```

The tree of **Task** can be awfully large and therefore, not loaded completely into memory. I could implement some type of object lazy loading or dynamic queries. Furthermore I will need an easy way to add new tasks with a function like Task::addSubtask... but my intuition is telling me that those solutions are wrong in so many levels.

I am trying to take some lessons about DDD from this problem. So I would like to find a confirmation to these assumptions.

1. Any aggregate root should always be fully loaded. Any partial load will require a subcomponent to be able to perform a query (through a repo, stored query...) which would brake many rules: single responsibility, ignorance of persistance mechanisms... (NOTE: I do not have an ORM layer providing lazy loading by default)
2. The "tree shape" of tasks in memory is actually only necessary for the Outline view in the GUI. Therefore I should have a dummy composite which can perform queries to the Service Layer of my Domain Model.
3. Since there is no reason to have a **Task** outside the context of a **Node**, my node repository should deal with any operation requiring the tree exploration, like:

   (List*) findChildrenOfTask(Task* aTask)

   (List*) findChildrenOfTask(Task* aTask, String regexInText)

   (void) addChildToTask(Task* aTask)

These are my assumptions, but I would like to confirm them with someone with more experience doing DDD. The "tree only in the GUI" also seems to spur some ideas of CQRS ideas. Is this problem one example of the benefits adopting CQRS for DDD?

Comment: Have you read [Effective Aggregate Design by Vaughn Vernon](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exact example is actually addressed in Vaughn Vernon's book *Implementing Domain Driven Design*

That said I invite you to ponder the following:

- Does task need to be transactionally consistent with Node? If not it can be its own Aggregate which dramatically simplifies things. Remember that you're thinking about this from the perspective of a command **ONLY**.
- If the tree is only for a query why not have a DTO worry about that instead of compromising your domain model?

I will fully admit that Vernon does a MUCH better job of explaining this than I do.

Comment: could you mention which chapter Vernon mentions that? It seems I skimmed way too fast over it! I was waiting to mature a little bit before a second read. However now I am starting to grasp one of the benefits of CQRS

Comment: Chapter 10, section: Rule: Design Small Aggregates

Comment: Oh! I do not need transactional consistency with Node... it was just scary facing a deep recursive database load without a framework providing lazy loading.

Comment: He covers that later in the book, you can't let your ORM dictate business logic. I realize the book is very dense, I would highly suggest reading it very carefully.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that! I was feeling "too square-headed" not wanting to rely on ORM and scaring myself by trying to implement lazy loading. I will see if the book answers my points, I remember Vernon was very good explaining the concepts and some implementation details, but lacking in the details I wanted, like the three points I mention. I guess I will just try to see what happens with a smart tree node for my GUI that can do queries.

Comment: From personal experience I highly suggest you walk away from code until you've finished the book, otherwise you'll end up re-coding everything about 10-15 times.

Comment: Mmmm... poor me, I went superficially around the book and felt that in my case, I do must mature the basics ideas just by coding and refactor everything as my knowledge matures. Learning advanced bounded context integration, Event Sourcing, CQRS and A+ES before mastering basic DDD paterns is overkill for me. Either I am too dumb to understand it without practice, or I am getting too old :-P